# Print multiple variable of an ID into single line with IDs and its single variable in a line?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a file with more than 10,000 entries:

```
TRINITY_DN4798_c0_g1_i1.p1 GO:0046658
TRINITY_DN4798_c0_g1_i1.p1 GO:0046659
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0003677|GO:0046983
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0000977|GO:0045944
```

I am trying to edit my file to look like:

```
TRINITY_DN4798_c0_g1_i1.p1 GO:0046658
TRINITY_DN4798_c0_g1_i1.p1 GO:0046659
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0003677
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0046983
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0000977
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0045944
```

I have tried using sed:

```
cat file | head | sed 's/|/\n/g'| sort -u
```

but getting output:

```
GO:0045944
GO:0046983
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0000977
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0003677
TRINITY_DN4798_c0_g1_i1.p1 GO:0046658
TRINITY_DN4798_c0_g1_i1.p1 GO:0046659
```

Need help, thanks.

Comment: Seems you only need a fixed amount of bytes, something like `cut -c 1-37 file`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
sed -E 's/^(.*)(GO:.*)\|(.*)$/\1\2\n\1\3/'
```

Output:

```
TRINITY_DN4798_c0_g1_i1.p1 GO:0046658
TRINITY_DN4798_c0_g1_i1.p1 GO:0046659
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0003677
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0046983
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0000977
TRINITY_DN4326_c0_g1_i3.p1 GO:0045944
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using awk:

```
awk -F"[ |]" '{print $1 OFS $2}$3{print $1 OFS $3}' file
```

Split using space and pipe as delimiter. So you end up getting 3 tokens. Print 1st and 2nd. Whenever 3rd is present, print 1st and 3rd.